# Analyzing bounced emails - Any free libraries for dotnet available?

Tags: .net, email-bounces

Does anyone know of a free/open library to analyze bounced emails?

Comment: What do you want to analyze at a bounced email?

Comment: The bounce type (hard/soft), the bounce reason.